# netbeans for c/c++ saying "no compiler found"

Tags: c++, netbeans-7, netbeans-plugins

I have tried the this [tutorial](http://netbeans.org/community/releases/70/cpp-setup-instructions.html) but it did not help me out. I have installed Cygwin and added its C:\cygwin\bin path in my environment variables but nothing happened, still the same error.
and its not even recognizing cout.

Comment: Have you tested gcc command under cygwin? Does it compiles good?

Answer (score 0):

The [configuration page](http://netbeans.org/community/releases/70/cpp-setup-instructions.html#compilers_windows) lists the required cygwin packages:

- gcc
- g++ (gcc-g++ package)
- gdb
- make

Make sure those packages are installed by re-running the Cygwin Setup and checking those packages in the Select Packages step.  Look under the Devel category or search for the packages in the Search field.

If the packages are marked "Skip" then they are not installed. Click the skipped packages until a version number appears where "Skip" did.

Then, click Next, let Cygwin install any dependencies, and click Next again to download and install the packages.